# sorting and selecting data

Tags: python, sql, sorting, select

I have huge tables of data that I need to manipulate (sort, calculate new quantities, select specific rows according to some conditions and so on...). So far I have been using a spreadsheet software to do the job but this is really time consuming and I am trying to find a  more efficient way to do the job.

I use python but I could not figure out how to use it for such things. I am wondering if anybody can suggest something to use. SQL?!

Comment: what database technology are you using? oracle, mysql?

Comment: SQL would probably work well. The fact that you couldn't even work out if SQL is the right tool indicates to me that you might experience quite a learning curve to actually use it though.

Comment: What format do you have the data in?

Comment: the files are in csv and FITS

Comment: @gnibbler I have used SQL a little bit before

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question, but there are multiple things that you can do to possibly make your life easier.

1.CSV   These are very useful if you are storing data that is ordered in columns, and if you are looking for easy to read text files.

2.Sqlite3   Sqlite3 is a database system that does not require a server to use (it uses a file instead), and is interacted with just like any other database system. However, for very large scale projects that are handling massive amounts of data, it is not recommended.

3.MySql    MySql is a database system that requires a server to interact with, but can be tweaked for very large scale projects, as well as small scale projects.

There are many other different types of systems though, so I suggest you search around and find that perfect fit. However, if you want to mess around with Sqlite3 or CSV, both Sqlite3 and CSV modules are supplied in the standard library with python 2.7 and 3.x I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably appreciate the `sqlite3` module in Python standard library:

- http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

You get a SQL database that's stored in a file on disk, with no need to configure a separate database server.  It's not appropriate for multiple clients accessing at once, but for a single-threaded analysis application like yours, it's a good fit.

Comment: sqlite3 can support multiple clients accessing it at once, however, only one client at a time can be making changes to the DB at once. See: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Comment: Looks like sqlite3 is the way to go!